# ASP.NET save complex entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Good day, I am new at ASP.NET and I can't figure out why my code doesn't work. I have model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
public class News
{
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture picture { get; set; }
    public int guid { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public int PictureId { get; set; }
    public byte[] image { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int hash { get; set; }
}
}
```

And I am trying to create new "News" via post form:

```
    // POST: News/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(News news, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage != null)
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
            {
                imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
            }
            news.picture = new Picture()
            {
                hash = 0,
                image = imageData,
                width = 0,
                height = 0
            };
            db.News.Add(news);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(news);
    }
```

But when I retrieve data from db I get null pointer exception:
, when I called debugger, I figure out that "news.picture" value is null. But before db.SaveChanges() it 100% not null. Looks like I am doing something stupidly wrong, bcs I can't find some1 who faced this problem. Thx.

Comment: I dont know why, but when I add virtual property all works:
"public virtual Picture picture { get; set; }"

Comment: Yeah the virtual property says that this will be lazily navigated. Generally everyone has `public virtual` on all navigation properties

Comment: Several changes I would make - firstly put a `public int PictureId {get; set;}` on the news model, which will put a foreign key there. Then attribute it will `[ForeignKey("Picture")]` where the `"Picture"` is the virtual navigation property. In the picture entity, you can remove `Picture` from the `Id` name as with the news entity. This makes it cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but when I add virtual property all works:

```
public virtual Picture picture { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(News news, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage != null)
        {
            byte[] imageData = null;
            using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
            {
                imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
            }
            var picture = new Picture()
            {
                hash = 0,
                image = imageData,
                width = 0,
                height = 0
            };
            db.Pictures.Add(picture); // make sure that the picture was tracked by the EF
            news.picture = picture;
            db.News.Add(news);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(news);
    }
```

Comment: That won't matter, if you attached the model via a navigation property it will create the entity in the database and associated it with the news entity.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following changes and see if it helps.

```
namespace WebApp.Models
{
  public class News
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("Picture")]
      public int PictureId { get; set; }
      public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }

      // not sure why this is here
      public int guid { get; set; }
  }

  public class Picture
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
      public string ContentType { get; set; }

      public int width { get; set; }
      public int height { get; set; }
      public int hash { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The Controller:

```
// POST: News/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(NewsDto news, HttpPostedFileBase uploadImage)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && uploadImage != null)
    {
        var imageData = byte[uploadImage.ContentLength];
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(uploadImage.InputStream))
        {
            imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(uploadImage.ContentLength);
        }

        var newsEntity = new New {
          Title = news.Title,
          Description = news.Description,
          Picture = new Picture()
          {
              ImageData = imageData,
              ContentType = contentType // I would get that from the HttpPostedFileBase
          }
        }

        // I always wrap my database connections in a using.
        using (var db = new DbContext()) {
          db.News.Add(newsEntity);
          db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(news);
}
```